# Spring framework. Set proxy for all controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

How can i set proxy for all my controllers in spring framework?
I wanna change the return expresion of my controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using Spring MVC 3.* and an XML configuration. If this is not the case, please let me know and I will update my answer accordingly.

Spring MVC provides the [HandlerInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) interface which can be used to both pre and post process requests handled by all Controllers. I would suggest that you create and implementation of this interface and use the postHandle() method to change the output of your Controllers accordingly.

Once you have your HandlerInterceptor implementation complete, you will need to instruct Spring MVC to use it. The namespace configuration for Spring MVC makes this very easy. As an example:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
            <bean class="com.example.MyInterceptor" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

In this example I am registering a single HandlerInterceptor implemented by the class com.example.MyInterceptor. I am also configuring Spring MVC to have the HandlerInterceptor implementation work on all requests. You can of course change the mapping to suit your application needs.